# Passing Method name and Arguments dynamically to thread.Start

Tags: c#, multithreading, object, parameters, arguments

Reworking of an old question:

I have a method that simplifies my threading quite a lot, but I'm having issues passing more than one argument to it!

```
public static Thread StartThread(ParameterizedThreadStart targetMethod, object argument)
{
            Thread result = null;

            result = new Thread(targetMethod);

            result.Start(argument);
            return result;
}
```

Is there any way I could pass more then one argument to `result.Start(argument)`? Or is there some other way of doing this while keeping it scalable?

Any help would be awesome :)

Thanks~ Daniel

Answer (score 2):

It's very simple

```
static void targetMethod(object obj)
{
    Tuple<string, int> tuple = (Tuple<string, int>)obj;
    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2);
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(targetMethod);
    thread.Start(new Tuple<string, int>("simple string", 123));
    thread.Join();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass [**Tuple**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) object in object argument to `StartThread` method. The other preferred way could be passing object of some `class` or `interface` instead of Tuple.

```
object population = new Tuple<string, int>("a", 1);
```

Type cast object containing tuple back to tuple in `targetMethod`.

```
private void  targetMethod(object t)
{
    Tuple<string, int> t = (Tuple<string, int>)population;
    string yourStringVariable = t.Item1;  
    int yourIntVariable = t.Item2;
}
```

Comment: At this point would it not be more effective to cast the object to a interface instead of a tuple?? That way I could just write the argument as a => expression

Comment: You can pass anything to object could be interface, you would need Func to use expression IMO

Comment: What would run faster?? This method is called quite a bit so it's worth it to me to optimize the runtime of this code.

Comment: You can calulate the time taken by both methods by calling them to number of times and using StopWatch to get the time before and after calls

Comment: I will give it a shot and report back! Thanks!